# Extend multiple classes in angular

Tags: angular

**I want to achieve:**

```
export class MyComponent extends AbstractClass1, AbstractClass2
```

I went through the following typescript mixin that could help in this case:

```
applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
        baseCtors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach((name) => {
                if (name !== 'constructor') {
                    derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

Now, I am not sure how to implement it to achieve my result. I couldn't find any documentation with respect to angular. Do we have to do it in the same component or create a new base component? How can it be achieved? I tried using it directly after extends, but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using mixins because they were broken multiple times in Angular.

Here is an example:

```
class AbstractClass1 {
    public sayAbstract1(word: string) {
      console.log('AbstractClass1: ' + word);
    }
}

class AbstractClass2 {
    public sayAbstract2(word: string) {
      console.log('AbstractClass2: ' + word);
    }
}

class MyComponent {

}

interface MyComponent extends AbstractClass1, AbstractClass2 {}

applyMixins(MyComponent, [AbstractClass1, AbstractClass2]);

const instance = new MyComponent();

instance.sayAbstract1('Hi!');
instance.sayAbstract2('Hi!');

function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, constructors: any[]) {
  constructors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach((name) => {
      Object.defineProperty(
        derivedCtor.prototype,
        name,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name) ||
          Object.create(null)
      );
    });
  });
}
```

See more examples here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you still need to decorate you base class with a dummy @Component. The mixin you are looking at is a different approach: composition. You're goal is describing inheritance. If you want to compose your class of behaviors from another class, take a look at my handy-typescript [mixin decorator](https://github.com/robbiemu/handy-typescript/blob/main/src/decorators/mixin.decorator.ts) -- you might find the [tests](https://github.com/robbiemu/handy-typescript/blob/main/src/decorators/tests/mixin.decorator.spec.ts) to be more explicit.

caveat emptor: This was developed for an earlier version of typescript, and was updated about half a year ago, but it may not be current. I've been sick with a bone infection since then and havent had a chance to work on stuff like that for a while.

Answer (score -1):

In Angular, you don't extend classes. This is not how the framework works.

Instead, you use interface composition (`OnInit`, `AfterViewInit`, etc), dependency injection and inversion of control.

This makes the code more reusable and decouples classes from each other.

So instead of your approach, consider doing this

```js
export class MyComponent {

  doOne = this.one.doOne.bind(this.one);
  doTwo = this.two.doTwo.bind(this.two);

  constructor(
    private one: AbstractClass1, 
    private two: AbstractClass2
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: We can extend classes in Angular. Google also does it in Angular Material components.

Comment: Because they want to share a common base. Try finding multiple classes extensions in material, I'm pretty sure you won't be able to.